# Libgdx Dialog not showing text

Tags: text, libgdx, dialog, label

I have a `Dialog` with a `Label` and a `TextButton`. The `TextButton` is displayed correctly, but the I can't see the `Label` text. However the `Dialog` gets larger if the text inside the `Label` is longer and gets smaller if the text is shorter.

The code that I use:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Warning", uiSkin) {
                            public void result(Object obj) {
                                System.out.println("result "+obj);
                            }
                        };
Label warningLabel = new Label("Invalid data", uiSkin);
dialog.text(warningLabel);
dialog.setMovable(false);
TextButton warningButton = new TextButton("OK", uiSkin, "small");
dialog.button(warningButton);
dialog.key(Keys.ENTER, true); 
if(!password.getText().equals(passwordRepeat.getText())){
                            dialog.show(signupStage);
                        }
```

Comment: It may be silly but are colors of dialog and text different?

Comment: It seems they were the same color. I manually changed the color using `warningLabel.setColor(Color.BLACK)` and now it is visible. Thanks!

Comment: LOL simple solutions are always best :)